# Python: authentication credentials Exception: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token"

Tags: python, google-sheets

I wrote function which takes credentials and connect to the google sheet. I retrieved the data from `googlesheet` and everything works normal. For some reason sometimes it gives me an error. I searched a bit and found out there is a way to solve it and i changed my code below. But still the same problem. can anybody help me please?

That is my code:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name ('xxxx.json' , scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("Test")


def network_list(request,networkname=''):

gs_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet=wks.get_worksheet(2)

if credentials.access_token_expired:
      gs_client.login()  # refreshes the token

mylist = sheet.get_all_records()

listofvm=[]
for mydict in mylist:
    # print(mydict)
    for key, value in mydict.items():

        if mydict[key] == networkname:
            # print(mydict['Network']+'  ' + mydict['IP_address'] + ' ' + str(mydict['Total_Intentes']))
            # templist.append({'Build':mydict['Build'], 'VM_Name':mydict['VM_Name']})
            # print(mydict['VM_Name'])
            if mydict['VM_Name'] not in listofvm:
                listofvm.append(mydict['VM_Name'])


return render(request, 'vm_list.html',{'listofvm':listofvm, 'networkname':networkname})
```

And here is my error below

```
 APIError at /
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. 
    Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid 
    authentication credential. See 
    https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole- 
    project.",
   "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, folks, I found the answer. I just post here may be in the future somebody will need that one. All courses teach open google spreadsheet and then authorize your credentials but the key is here when you request to google sheet your tokens are changed that's why just before to request the data put "open" command after your credentials. I put here the right answer, I tried it, works very well.

My previous code

```
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    credentials=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name ('xxxx.json' , scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    wks = gc.open("Test")


    def network_list(request,networkname=''):

        gs_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
        sheet=wks.get_worksheet(2)

        if credentials.access_token_expired:
            gs_client.login()  # refreshes the token

        mylist = sheet.get_all_records()
```

The right answer

```
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    credentials=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name ('xxxx.json' , scope)
     gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)




     def network_list(request,networkname=''):

         gs_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
         wks = gc.open("Test")
         sheet=wks.get_worksheet(2)

         if credentials.access_token_expired:
             gs_client.login()  # refreshes the token

         mylist = sheet.get_all_records()
```

Answer (score 0):

Per default, the token you get [expires](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) within 1 hour, so that's why you will have to run again:

```
credentials=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name ('xxxx.json' , scope)
gs_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

or also you can try: `gc.login()`